# Conversion of UIView to PDF changes image colour

Tags: objective-c, pdf, image-processing, pdf-generation, cgcontext

I have a repeatable pattern within my app.

Here's the image as displayed within the app:

[image: Original Image]

Here's the same image as displayed after conversion to PDF:

[image: PDF Image - Pink bars instead of faded blue/grey]

As you can see by this, the image colour changes from a grey/green to a pink.
The PDF is loaded directly into an email ready for sending.

I'm not sure if this is something to do with the image itself being loaded into the PDF, or something related to the PDFing process. Either way, I've attached the code of the PDF process below.

Here's my PDF generation code:

```
- (NSData *)createPDFForView:(UIView *)view{        
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 600), nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 600)];
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData;
}
```

During the PDF process, I convert it to 50% of the size that it is by adjusting the frame, the image itself is not modified, just the view that contains the image; the image autoresizes within the frame.

Is there anything that can be done to stop this colour change from occurring?

Comment: what's in `layer.content`? Is it a file you can post? How did you set `layer.content`?

Comment: It's a series of images/text that I lay out in a A4 shape prior to making a PDF. The rest of the images and text appear fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF specification only supports JPEG, JPEG2000, TIFF & JBIG2 (and some other useless ones no one cares about.) Long story short is that whatever program you use to convert your document to PDF will be forced to convert the image to a compatible format, and JPEG is traditionally opted for in these cases.

So the reason is because the image was modified to JPEG without transparency, and using a PNG to JPEG converter that had no respect for retaining the appearance of your image. If the image had any color profiles these were likely stripped as well.

You will have considerably better results and more control over what goes on if you convert your images to JPEG before converting the document to PDF. This way the program will keep your images as they are, so you know exactly what you will get. This is also your only chance of specifying the color profile of the image.

If you can manage it, JPEG2000 is preferable over JPEG, especially if you're looking for lossless images.

Transparency can be achieved on a PDF but this is achieved with filters over the image object, irrespective of the image format used. However, that is a bit more advanced than what you are doing and probably not worth the time.

Comment: This seems the most plausible answer so far. I'll test.

Comment: You were right with this answer!
I'll happily award you the bounty.

Comment: Happy to help. You could use Jasper library for conversion to JPEG2000 if you want high quality images in a PDF without excessive file size.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the error, but not figured out the 'why' of it.

Essentially, the grey/blue colour was a transparent PNG.
I gave this a white background and re-saved the image and it seems to work fine.

I'll still award the bounty to anyone who can help me with the 'why'.

Comment: What exactly did you give a white background to, the PDF?

Comment: @Papouh The image file itself; so instead of embedding a transparent PNG, I embedded a PNG with a white background.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell without having the exact colors (and me without my copy of Photoshop on this computer...), but it seems like one of two things:

1. A color space conflict with the alpha channel of your image. I'm not sure quite how that could happen since you're grabbing the current context for your PDF rendering, but if your intended alpha value is being interpreted as the red value (for example, your image was made in RGBA and is being rendered in ARGB - and that intended alpha value's higher than the other values in your original gray color), that could definitely make a gray/blue image pinkish.
2. An issue with the color iOS uses as the "transparent color" when rendering PNGs. I kind of doubt this is the problem, and I couldn't find any documentation on the subject specific to iOS, but I throw it out there as a remote possibility. I'd look into #1 first.

Answer (score 0):

My guess to the WHY of it is that internally the image is converted to a JPEG. Since JPEG doesn't support transparency a background color is added to the transparent pixels. The added pixels are usually grey or black but it may be implementation dependant or related to a "background color" data field in the PNG.

The underlying issue is probably that the PDF standard doesn't really support embedded PNG. When it does render them it's typically because the creator software converted the data to uncompressed rastor bytes but that just bloats the file.

It may be more complicated than that even, according to [this adobe forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/846943) the issue is actually with Postscript so if UIView is doing a postscript->pdf conversion that'll cause this too.